# _loadViewFromNibNamed called even though no nib associated with UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, crash

I have a UIViewController subclass which I am instantiating and trying to push on to the navigationController like so :

```
MenuVC *menuVC = [[MenuVC alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:menuVC animated:YES];
```

I don't have a nib file associated with this class and so just doing a simple `..alloc] init]` instead of `initWithNib:bundle:`.

I am still getting a crash on the `pushViewController` call and the trace says this

```
reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "MenuVC" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
```

I don't see why this could be happening. I have other view controller which loads fine with the same method.

Comment: Does MenuVC override the init method by chance?

Comment: @Fraggle no it doesn't

Comment: Could there be an old MenuVC.nib in the app bundle?

Comment: Are you using a Story board for this?

Comment: @Fraggle no. I am not using Storyboard

Comment: I don't understand this. I deleted the file and rewrote the exact same code in a new file and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be an "answer" but this was resolved. I just removed the whole file and added a new file with a different name and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the answer to this in Apple's Docs :

> A view controller has an associated nib file if the nibName property returns a non-nil value, which occurs if the view controller was instantiated from a storyboard, if you explicitly assigned it a nib file using the initWithNibName:bundle: method, or if iOS finds a nib file in the app bundle with a name based on the view controller’s class name.

So, this means the OS actually tries to load the nib if it finds one. I did have a nib in my bundle with same name as VC but had not associated it's `File Owner`.

Comment: In my case nib file was left in a build folder, even though I have deleted corresponding xib file from the project. Fresh and clean build solved the problem: Cmd+Shift+K, Cmd+R.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is that the Viewcontroller have a view that comes in default and somehow that connection of IB to class view->view  went missing and hence the error